# ubuntustudio-controls instead of qjackctl 19.04

Tags: sound, 19.04, ubuntu-studio

I use Ubuntu studio to record professionally with Ardour.  My interface is a Focusrite Scarlett 18i20.  My usual qjackctl settings are 96k sample rate, 1024 frames/period, and 3 periods/buffer.

I saw in the release notes that I should "discontinue use of qjackctl."   I attempted to use ubuntu studio controls to set up a session.  The session seemed to initialize correctly, but when I got into the session, the 5th and 6th channels were experiencing what sounds like an X-Run.  I could not determine the frequency with which this was happening, but it seemed to be a regular or semi-regular intervals.

I went back to qjackctl and the issue did not persist.  Could someone from the Studio team please help problem solve this?

Also, I use Ubuntu studio with my recording business.  I do not code, but would like to be able to contribute somehow.  Is there a financial way to contribute to Ubuntu Studio? I love studio and would like to see it's development continue.
Thanks!
-Josh

Answer (score 2):

If qjackctl was working for you before, go ahead and use it. The settings you use in qjackctl should easily transfer to Ubuntu Studio Controls, so I find it peculiar that it's not working well. Disabling the PulseAudio bridge might help reduce your Xruns as it requires a higher buffer.

Unfortunately, there is no easy way to troubleshoot this easily via this forum, so I encourage you to join one of our chat support methods (and stay connected until someone can respond, be very patient) linked at https://ubuntustudio.org/support.